# Years cannot be shown by using loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

Full HTML code(The script in the head tag is image rotater):

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Credit card details</title>
        <link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="booking.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="val_registration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript1.2">
    var howOften = 5; //number often in seconds to rotate
    var current = 0; //start the counter at 0
    var ns6 = document.getElementById&&!document.all; //detect netscape 6

    // place your images, text, etc in the array elements here
    var items = new Array();
    items[0]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='photo01' src='photo01.jpg' height='237' width='750' border-style='inset' border-weight:'10px' /></a>"; //a linked image
    items[1]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='photo02' src='photo02.jpg' height='237' width='750' border-style='inset'  border-weight:'10px'/></a>"; //a linked image
    items[2]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='photo03' src='photo03.jpg' height='237' width='750' border-style='inset'  border-weight:'10px'/></a>"; //a linked image
    items[3]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='photo04' src='photo04.jpg' height='237' width='750' border-style='inset'  border-weight:'10px'/></a>"; //a linked image
    items[4]="<a href='link.htm'><img alt='photo05' src='photo05.jpg' height='237' width='750' border-style='inset'  border-weight:'10px'/></a>"; //a linked image

    function rotater() {
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = items[current];
        current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1;
        setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
    }

    function rotater() {
        if(document.layers) {
            document.placeholderlayer.document.write(items[current]);
            document.placeholderlayer.document.close();
        }
        if(ns6)document.getElementById("placeholderdiv").innerHTML=items[current]
            if(document.all)
                placeholderdiv.innerHTML=items[current];
                current = (current==items.length-1) ? 0 : current + 1; //increment or reset
                setTimeout("rotater()",howOften*1000);
    }
    window.onload=rotater;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="login" name="login">
        &nbsp <a href="login.htm" target="_self"> Login</a>&nbsp&nbsp<b><b>|</b></b>
        &nbsp<a href="signup.htm" target="_self">New user?</a>&nbsp&nbsp
    </div>

    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo" width="500" height="100" usemap="#logomap"/></br>
    <map id="logomap" name="logomap">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,743,146" href="home.htm" alt="home"/>
        <area shape="default" coords"0,0,743,146" href="home.htm" alt="home"/>
    </map></br>

    <div id="placeholderdiv"></div><br/>

    <div id="mlink" >
        <a href="home.htm" target="_self" id="home"> Home </a>
        <a href="aboutus.htm" target="_self" id="aboutus"> About Us </a>
        <a href="promotion.htm" target="_self" id="promotion"> Promotion </a>
        <a href="contactus.htm" target="_self" id="contactus"> Contact Us </a>
        <a href="faqs.htm" target="_self" id="faqs"> FAQs </a>  
    </div><br/>

    <div id="opac">
        <h1> Credit card details </h1>
    <hr/>
        <form id="cc_form" action="success(payment).html" method="post" onsubmit="return val_cc()">
        <table rules="none" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="cc_no">Credit card number:<span id="imp">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" id="cc_no" tabindex="1"/>
                <br/><span class="eg">&nbsp;eg:5678123445468909</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="cvv">Card Verification Value(Last 3 digits<br/> of credit card number):<span id="imp">*</span></label></td><td>
                <input type="text" id="cvv" tabindex="2"/><br/><span class="eg">&nbsp;eg:909</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="expiry_day">Expiry date(MM/YYYY):<span id="imp">*</span></label></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="expiry_month" tabindex="4">
                        <optgroup label="Month">
                        <option value="01">January</option>
                        <option value="02">February</option>
                        <option value="03">March</option>
                        <option value="04">April</option>
                        <option value="05">May</option>
                        <option value="06">June</option>
                        <option value="07">July</option>
                        <option value="08">August</option>
                        <option value="09">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>

                    <select id="expiry_year" tabindex="5">
                        <optgroup>
                        <script>generate_year();</script>   
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label for="cardholder">Cardholder's name(Name as displayed<br/> on the card):<span id="imp">*</span></label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="cardholder" tabindex="6"/><br/><span class="eg">&nbsp;eg:Yap Kar Kei</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm2" tabindex="7"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Cancel" id="cancel2" tabindex="8"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Notes: <span id="imp">*</span> indicates the column that must be filled</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <hr/>
    <b><i id="copyright">Copyrighted : &#169;  2014  I &hearts; Travels agency. </i></b>
</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function generate_year()            /*For generate cc year*/

{
    for (var i = 2014; i <= 2104; i++)

    {
        document.write ("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");

    }

}
```

Actually I want to show all the options in this format:2014.
However,I don't know what is wrong with my codes until all the years do not show up. (Beside January)

Comment: I can see the years into drop down.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/aj2qb/)

Comment: But this does not work for my website and I cant figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Is function **generate_year** available on your page?
I don't see this function in head script section in your full html code.
Your function **generate_year** is absolutely correct and it works.

Comment: Originally I put the function in a separate JavaScript file.After I found that it did not work,I put the function in the head section but what surprised me was it could work after I placed it under head section.So,is this the problem that causes the function cannot perform?

Comment: I used your full html code, put the function in the head after all javascript code and it worked perfectly. Do you see any error messages in the browser debugger tool (like Chrome dev tool)? It helps find you  answers on all your question.